# How to loop through array parameter via Powershell task in Azure DevOps

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have a parameter that consists of two executable paths and I want to loop through it to sign each executable. For this, I use a PowerShell@2 task that is passed via a template in Azure DevOps.

I don't seem to loop correctly through the executable array via any of the methods I've tried in my template code.

What is the best way to loop through the array parameter? Thanks for your help.

Here is my latest code:

```
parameters:
- name: executableList
  type: object
  default: []

steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: 'Sign executables'
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      #...more code here
          ${{ foreach (executable in  parameters.executableList) }} {
            & $signingExecutable sign /sm /s My /n "Sign Text" /tr http://rfc3161timestamp.globalsign.com/advanced /td sha256 /fd sha256 "$(Pipeline.Workspace)$executable"
          }
```

Error: While scanning a simple key, could not find expected ':'.

Comment: Did you refer to the documentation on looping in Azure Pipelines? `foreach` is not a valid keyword. The syntax you're using is completely incorrect.

Comment: @DanielMann that's a PowerShell script using foreach. Syntax may still be incorrect, though, since it doesn't work.

Comment: `${{ }}` is Azure Pipelines compile-time expression syntax, not PowerShell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [convertToJson](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#converttojson) function. Small example:

```
parameters:
- name: myArray
  type: object
  default: 
  - "1"
  - "2"
  - "4"
  - "8"
  - "16"

steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: 'Sign executables'
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
     $mayarrstr= @"
     ${{ convertToJson(parameters.myArray) }}
     "@
     $myarr = ConvertFrom-Json $mayarrstr
     
     foreach ($myvalue in $myarr)
     {
       Write-Host "Value: " $myvalue
     }
```